# javascript animation error in chrome: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have encountered the error: Cannot read property 'style' of null  in my animation code when I open my html with my chrome, but it worked nicely in Edge and Firefox. I have tried to move the animation to the bottom and also tried to separate the java code and move the code of generating the blocks to higher position, but it still doesn't work in chrome, is there any thing I missed?

here is the html:

`<div id = "room"></div>
    <script src = "js.js"></script>`

here is the js:

```
        var test = document.getElementById("test");
        var text = "<div class = \"wrapAll\">";

        //generate number on top
        text += "<div class = \"floatNumleft1\">" +1+ "</div>";
        for (i = 2; i < 9 ; i++){
            text += "<div class = \"floatNumleft\">" +i+ "</div>";

            }
        text += "<div class = \"floatNumright1\">" +8+ "</div>";
        for (i = 7; i > 0 ; i--){
            text += "<div class = \"floatNumright\">" +i+ "</div>";

            }
        text += "<br style = \"clear:both\" />";    

        //generate box
        for (i = 15; i > 0; i--){
            if(i%5 == 0 || i == 1){
            text += "<div class = \"floatFloorL\">" +i+ "/F"+ "</div>";
            text += "<div class = \"floatFloorR\">" +(i+15)+ "/F" +"</div>";

            }
            else {
            text += "<div class = \"floatFloorL\">" + "</div>";
            text += "<div class = \"floatFloorR\">" +"</div>";

            }
            for (j = 1; j < 9; j++){
                text += "<div class = \"wrapperL\"><div class = \"wrapperLeft\"  onclick = \"functionAnime(this)\"><div id = \"id"+(i*100+j)+"\" class = \"floatingblock\" >"+(i*100+j)+ "</div></div></div>";
            }
            for (j = 8; j > 0; j--){
                if(i == 11 && j == 2){
                text += "<div class = \"wrapperR\"><div class = \"wrapperRight\"  onclick = \"functionAnime(this)\"><div id = \"id"+(i*100+1500+j)+"\" class = \"floatingblock\"  style = \"background-color: white; color: black;\" >"+(i*100+1500+j)+ "</div></div></div>";
                continue;
                }
                if (i == 3 && j == 3) {
                text += "<div class = \"wrapperR\"><div class = \"wrapperRight\"  onclick = \"functionAnime(this)\"><div id = \"id"+(i*100+1500+j)+"\" class = \"floatingblock\"  style = \"background-color: white; color: black;\"  >"+(i*100+1500+j)+ "</div></div></div>";
                continue;
                }

                text += "<div class = \"wrapperR\"><div class = \"wrapperRight\"  onclick = \"functionAnime(this)\"><div id = \"id" +(i*100+1500+j)+ "\" class = \"floatingblock\" >" +(i*100+1500+j)+ "</div></div></div>";
            }

            if(i%5 == 0 || i == 1){
            text += "<div class = \"floatFloorLmid\">" +i+ "/F"+ "</div>";
            text += "<div class = \"floatFloorRmid\">" +(i+15)+ "/F" +"</div>";             
            }
            text += "<br style = \"clear:both\" />";

        }
        text += "</div>";
        document.getElementById("room").innerHTML = text;

        //Animation
        function fAnimeInner(id) {

            var elem = document.getElementById(id);
            var color = elem.style.backgroundColor;
            if (color === "rgb(255, 255, 255)") {

                elem.classList.remove("animation");
                elem.classList.add("animation");
                elem.style.animationName = "transformInnerWhite";
                elem.style.webkitAnimationName = "transformInnerWhite";
                elem.style.backgroundColor = "#FFA500";
                elem.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
            }
            else {


                elem.classList.remove("animation");
                elem.classList.add("animation");
                elem.style.animationName = "transformInnerOrange";
                elem.style.webkitAnimationName = "transformInnerOrange";
                elem.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
                elem.style.color = "#000000";
            }
        }


        function functionAnime(elem) {

            var id;

            elem.style.position = "relative";
            elem.classList.remove("animation");
            void elem.offsetWidth;
            elem.classList.add("animation");
            id = "id" + elem.innerText;

            elem.style.animationName = "transformOuter";
            elem.style.webkitanimationName = "transformOuter";
            fAnimeInner(id);
        }'
```

the console said that the problem is at fanimeinner and fanimation and htmldivelement.onclick.

what it said in the console was:Uncaught TypeError: 
Cannot read property 'style' of null at fAnimeInner (js.js:60) at functionAnime (js.js:95) at HTMLDivElement.onclick (test border.html:20)

I understand that the document.getElementById(id) is returning null, but I don't understand why and I also want to know why it works fine in chrome and firefox

Comment: exactly which line that reported error ? what "id" fAnimeInner get ? are you sure that `var elem = document.getElementById(id);` can find element ?

Comment: what it said in the console was:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at fAnimeInner (js.js:60)
    at functionAnime (js.js:95)
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (test border.html:20)   
I understand that the document.getElementById(id) is returning null, but I don't understand why and I also want to know why it works fine in chrome and firefox

Comment: `id = "id" + elem.innerText;` ... so your id's start with the string `'id'` ?

Comment: The first line of your JS references an element ID that isn't in the HTML shown in the question.

Comment: yes, i start my id with string id, which is also generate with the for loop in js. for the first line of my js, that is useless for the code, as when i was debugging, i tried to use that element which is blank and only contain a color rule to compare at  '  if (color === "rgb(255, 255, 255)")' but i think it is not the problem now

Comment: try `console.log()` to see what you got for `id` in `fAnimeInner(id)` then try execute `document.getElementById(id)` in console manually

Comment: i added `console.log(id)` just below `fAnimeInner(id)`, and when i press a block, it gives out idxxxx where xxxx is the number of the block. e.g. if i press the block with number 1505, it do give id1505

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your line:

```
id = "id" + elem.innerText;
```

with:

```
id = "id" + elem.innerText.trim();
```

Comment: Because there were some spaces around the id string that are showed only in google chrome. Trim function removes all unnecessary spaces from string.